# perl 500 Internal Server Error php include

Tags: php, perl

I am trying to run PHP file in Perl using [`PHP::Include`](http://search.cpan.org/~esummers/PHP-Include-0.2/lib/PHP/Include.pm) but browser getting `500 Internal Server Error`

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use PHP::Include;
include_php_vars( 'file.php' );
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "<H1>Hello World</H1>\n";
```

Comment: Check your error log for a more detailed error message.

Comment: Check the server log for the error message.

Answer (score 0):

test your file.php for compilation errors.

```
php file.php
```

while in that folder, test the script you are using

```
perl scriptname.pl
```

so that std error will be displayed (instead of the generic 500 error you are seeing when running the script through CGI).

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you are printing your header (`print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";`) after doing the php include. Depending on what is actually in your php script, any non-header output before the header would result in a 500 error.